# Dynamic Table with typescript and html

Tags: html, typescript, dynamic

Currently I do small exercises with typescript and html. This includes building a table in which I can add, edit and delete items.I am now stuck where I want to edit or delete an item.

I simply add HTML code via the function to the website. Now I want to give the object to the onclick function. Thus, when the function is triggered, I directly have the corresponding object.
At the moment however my IDE says when calling the function deleteUser from the function toTableString in the HTML :`Unresolved variable or type user`

The Code:

```
interface IUser {
    firstName: string,
    lastName: string,
    userName: string,
    password: string
}

class User implements IUser {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    password: string;
    userName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string, password: string, userName: string) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.password = password;
        this.userName = userName;
    }
}

let list: Array<IUser> = []

function createUser() {

    const firstNameInput = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('first-name')).value;
    const lastNameInput = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('last-name')).value;
    const userNameInput = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('user-name')).value;
    const passwordInput = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById('password')).value;

    list.push(new User(firstNameInput, lastNameInput, passwordInput, userNameInput));

    (<HTMLFormElement>document.getElementById("createUserForm")).reset();

    updateTable()
}

function updateTable() {

    let tableString: string = "<table class=\"table\"><thead><tr><th scope=\"col\">#</th><th scope=\"col\">First Name</th><th scope=\"col\">Last Name</th><th scope=\"col\">User Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>"
    for (let _i = 0; _i < list.length; _i++) {
        let user: IUser = list[_i];

        tableString = tableString + toTableString(_i, user);
    }

    tableString = tableString + "</tbody></table>";

    (<HTMLSpanElement>document.getElementById("userTable")).innerHTML = tableString;
}

function toTableString(row: number, user: IUser): string {
    return "<tr><th scope=\"row\">" + (row + 1) + "</th><td>" + user.firstName + "</td><td>" + user.lastName + "</td><td>" + user.lastName + "</td><td><span class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-pencil\"></span></td><td><span  onclick='deleteUser(user)' class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-trash\"></span></td></tr>";
}

function deleteUser(user: IUser) {
    alert(user.userName)
}

function editUser(user: IUser) {

}
```

The result should be that if function

```
function deleteUser (user: IUser) {
    alert (user.userName)
}
```

is called, the corresponding name is the output.

Thanks for your help and if you have general suggestions for improvement then you are welcome to write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a bit more and came to this solution which now works for me.

```
function addUserToTable(user: IUser, index: number) {
    // Get a reference to the table
    let table = <HTMLTableElement>document.getElementById("userTable");


    let newRow = table.tBodies[0].insertRow(-1);

    let number = newRow.insertCell(0);

    let firstName = newRow.insertCell(1);

    let lastName = newRow.insertCell(2);

    let userName = newRow.insertCell(3);

    let edit = newRow.insertCell(4);

    let del = newRow.insertCell(5);
    // Append a text node to the cell
    number.appendChild(document.createTextNode("" + index));
    firstName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(user.firstName));
    lastName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(user.lastName));
    userName.appendChild(document.createTextNode(user.userName));


    let editSpan = document.createElement("span");
    editSpan.setAttribute("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-pencil");
    editSpan.setAttribute("data-toggle", "modal");
    editSpan.setAttribute("data-target", "#updateUserModal");

    editSpan.addEventListener('click', function () {
        editUser(user);
    });

    edit.appendChild(editSpan);

    let delSpan = document.createElement("span");
    delSpan.setAttribute("class", "glyphicon glyphicon-trash");


    delSpan.addEventListener('click', function () {
        deleteUser(user);
    });

    del.appendChild(delSpan);
}

function updateTable() {
    let table = <HTMLTableElement>document.getElementById("userTable");
    var new_tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    table.replaceChild(new_tbody, table.tBodies[0])

    list.forEach((user, index) => {
        addUserToTable(user, index + 1)
    })
}
```

With the DomParser I had further problems that it did't find any methods in the execution. Everything was okay while compiling

Answer (score 0):

This will not work that way. Any variables directly in the HTML will resolve in that context only. The `user` argument in `toTableString` will not be accessible to the HTML.

In general when working with the DOM you may want to parse it and then attach the events in code. There also are a ton of templating/binding libraries that can help with that.

User can be simplified:

```
class User implements IUser
{
    constructor(
        public firstName: string,
        public lastName: string,
        public password: string,
        public userName: string
    ) { }
}
```

Here i parse the Table skeleton, then add rows to it and replace the old table directly (if the table already exists there is no need to recreate it though, you can just clear the rows and add new ones):

```
function updateTable()
{
    const tableString: string = /*html*/`
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">First Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Last Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">User Name</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody></tbody>
        </table>`;

    const parser = new DOMParser();
    /** Parses an element and assigns the correct type. */
    const parse = <T extends HTMLElement>(str: string) =>
        <T>parser.parseFromString(str, 'text/html').documentElement;

    const table = parse<HTMLTableElement>(tableString);

    list.forEach((user, index) =>
    {
        const rowString = toTableString(index, user);
        const row = parse<HTMLTableRowElement>(rowString);

        // Adding handler to DOM here (identified via attribute).
        row.querySelector('[data-delete-button]')!.addEventListener('click', () => deleteUser(user));

        table.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);
    });

    const existingTable = document.getElementById("userTable");
    existingTable.parentElement.replaceChild(table, existingTable);
}

function toTableString(row: number, user: IUser): string
{
    return /*html*/`<tr>
        <th scope="row">${row + 1}</th>
        <td>${user.firstName}</td>
        <td>${user.lastName}</td>
        <td>${user.lastName}</td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" data-delete-button></span></td>
    </tr>`;
}
```

Using template literals (strings terminated by backticks) allows you to have line breaks and you can insert your data via `${...}`. Also you can have it be highlighted correctly in your editor, e.g.:

[image: vs code]

Note however that you should **never** construct HTML this way from anything containing user input without escaping it properly first.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.
Currently my tbody is still undefined. 
How can I solve this in this case:
    table.tBodies[0].appendChild(row);